# I'm developing an app which contain 2 users one admin and client but I can't login for both users between I'm using react native & firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I'm trying to display different screen based on the login users but I can't login at all for both user

**Here is my login screen code:**

```js
const SignIn = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null); // This user

  const handleSignIn = () => {
    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((userCredentials) => {
        const user = userCredentials.user;
        console.log("Logged in with", user.email);
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        {
          user?.role === "admin" ? <AdminNavi /> : <UserNavi />;
        }

        const userData = await db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).get();
        setUser(userData.data());
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
    });
    return () => unsubscribe;
  }, []);
};
```

**here is the admin Navigation screen code:**

```js
const AdminNavi = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthNavigator} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="AdminTabs" component={AdminTabs} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Stack" component={StackNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**Here is the user Navigation screen code:**

```js
const UserNavi = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthNavigator} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Stack" component={StackNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**Here is my app.js code:**

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      // don't know what code I should put here after user login... as I have
      already specified in login screen if user is admin go to adminNavi either
      go to client
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

So what I want to do is when the admin login the admin navi will display with its own tab bottom and when the client login the client navi will display. I was trying to fix it but unfortunately I couldn't. any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `user?.role === "admin" ? <AdminNavi /> : <UserNavi />;`


I think instead of simply returning it here which won't do anything. You need to call `navigation.navigate(routeName)` so it navigates to that specific navigator.

Comment: so do you mean ? I should replace user?.role === "admin" ? <AdminNavi /> : <UserNavi />; by user?.role === "admin" ? navigation.navigate('AdminScreen') : ('UserScreen') instead ? is this what do  you mean ?

Comment: Yes, if I understand your code correctly, what you have currently is doing nothing. Try adding the navigate code and see if that works.

Comment: Great, I've created an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current logic for returning AdminNaiv/UserNavi doesn't work because it's not returning anything or navigating anywhere.

`user?.role === "admin" ? <AdminNavi /> : <UserNavi />;`

To navigate correctly you need to use `navigation.naviate(routeName)` to navigate to the route you want to.

So you should change it to:

`user?.role === "admin" ? navigation.navigate('AdminScreen') : ('UserScreen')`